# How to send e-mail to node author 1w before date field in node?

Tags: 7, emails, rules

I've got a content type with date fields. What I'd like to do is send a reminder e-mail to the post author one week before the value of the date field, with the rules module, or in another way. How would you go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Requirements

Rules, Rules UI, Rules Scheduler, Date, and Date API modules

#### Add date field

Go to your content types Manage Fields and add a field of type Date.

I called mine `Deadline`, machine name: field_deadline

### Create a Rule

Action: After saving new content
Type: Article

[image]

This is all you have to do for now, will get back to this rule later.

## Create a component

Component Plugin: Rule

[image]

**Component action**

- Add action of **`Fetch Entity by Property`**

[image]

- Add action **`Send Mail`**

**To:** `[author-email:0]`

[image]

## Edit your Rule now

- Add action of **`Schedule component evaluation`**. In SCHEDULED EVALUATION DATE click on the grey <kbd>switch to data selection</kbd> button. (not visible in screenshot since I already click it)

[image]

---

## Testing

Go to the components tab and click on schedule

[image]

You'll need to click those grey <kbd>switch to ...</kbd>  buttons to get it to look like mine.

Put a node ID in the last one.

[image]

---

#### Important

Your e-mail will get sent once the time has been reached, but **also once cron runs**. So if your cron runs once a day, it may not get sent until the day after, so you may need to adjust your cron to run more often.

You might want to use [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) so you can schedule specific crons to run at different intervals, instead of running everything every x minutes, days, hours.